# Resources not being released when unloading AppDomain

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, appdomain

I'm currently having a problem with resources apparently not being released after unload of a AppDomain, so I end up with strange errors, due to lack of resources at some point in time.

I thought by having the code running in it's own AppDomain, one could be sure that all resource allocated in that AppDomain would be released ?

I was under the impression that I would be able to isolate resource leaks in 3'rd party components by running them in their own appdomain ?

Some of the errors are:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\guaapdsj.dll'.
File name: 'C:\Windows\TEMP\guaapdsj.dll'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
.
```

Another one:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not enough storage is available to process this command
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.EnsureResourceChangeListener()
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindThemeStyle(DependencyObjectType key)
```

One more

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not enough storage is available to process this command
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(Int32 dwExStyle, String lpszClassName, String lpszWindowName, Int32 style, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, HandleRef hWndParent, HandleRef hMenu, HandleRef hInst, Object pvParam)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.EnsureResourceChangeListener()
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
   at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindThemeStyle(DependencyObjectType key)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetThemeStyle(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateThemeStyleProperty()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFireInitialized()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
   at System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.OnHeaderChanged(Object oldHeader, Object newHeader)
```

Comment: These are operating resources, not .NET objects that an AppDomain can manage.  The only way to protect yourself from bad code that leaks handles is throw it away or run it in another process that you can Kill().

Comment: So what you are saying is, that instead of running it in another AppDomain, I should run it in it's own process ?

Comment: Most lickly you are failing to call Dispose() on a object somewhere.    Just removing say a control from anther WinForm control is not enough.     Use a good memory profiler to find out where the problem allocations are being done.   I have found that Redrate tools are good for this.